# Getting Results of a Regression based of part of a dataframe as a result in a new column in R

Tags: r

I'm writing a paper in R and I'm a total noob when it comes to good programming.
My question is the following.
I have a large dataframe. For simplification a part of it would look like this.

```
a <- data.frame(firm = rep(c("a","b"), each=10), return=runif(20), Mrkt=rep(1,20), trfd=rep(1,20))
```

But with much more data and different values for Mrkt.
What I would like to generate is a simple linear regression, where Mrkt is the independent variable (X) and return is the dependent variable (Y). Also this regression should be done separately for every firm in my sample. Then I would like the resulting coefficient from every regression in a new column next to trfd.

So my desired output would look like this:

```
Result <- data.frame(firm = rep(c("a","b"), each=10), return=runif(20), Mrkt=rep(1,20), trfd=rep(1,20),Coefficient=rep(c("c","d"),each=10))
```

With c and d are equal to the regression coefficients.

I hope the question does make sense to you and the example dataframe is in a proper manner. Otherwise please ask me. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: This example for is very similar to what you want to do: https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls13_list-columns.html#nested_data_frame,_modelling,_and_gapminder

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped!